# How can I replace a string using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a few divs with comma separated values in each. If the word 'public' is present in the values, I want to display the word 'Yes'. Else, I want to display the word 'No'. I am using if else and indexOf. Should I be using.each(function () instead?

```
<div class="open-public">ses, public</div>
<div class="open-public">public, der</div>
<div class="open-public">public</div>
<div class="open-public">fder, stn</div>
<div class="open-public">public</div>
<div class="open-public">stn</div>


    var s = $(".open-public").text().trim();
    var match = s.split(', ')
    console.log(match)
    console.log(s)
 
 if (~match.indexOf("public")) {
      $('.open-public').text("Yes");
    } else {
      $('.open-public').text('No');
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
    $(".open-public").each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':contains("public")').text("Yes");
    } else {
        $('.open-public').text('No');
    }
});
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Paul2167/b5t9c2dk/44/)

Comment: I tried it here but I think I am missing something. [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Paul2167/ujsr5kdg/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.each` approach is the correct one but you really don't need jQuery for this.

For matching the text, I would recommend either splitting the CSV text value into an array or using a regex to match the entire word "public".

```js
const rx = /\bpublic\b/ // use word-boundaries to match the entire word
document.querySelectorAll(".open-public").forEach(el => {
  el.textContent = rx.test(el.textContent) ? "Yes" : "No"
})
```

```html
<div class="open-public">ses, public</div>
<div class="open-public">public, der</div>
<div class="open-public">public</div>
<div class="open-public">fder, stn</div>
<div class="open-public">public</div>
<div class="open-public">stn</div>
```

---

If you're set on using jQuery, it might look something like this

```js
const rx = /\bpublic\b/
$(".open-public").each(function() {
  const $this = $(this)
  $this.text(rx.test($this.text()) ? "Yes" : "No")
})
```

Comment: This works great. thank you. [newest fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Paul2167/rgt96w20/2/)